# How to set the Organiser of a meeting from a .net application accessing Exchange Web Service

Tags: .net, exchangewebservices

In a .net application deployed on an intranet - I am trying to get it so that on a certain page a user can set up an appointment in the Outlook calendars of various people listed on the page.

To create an ExchangeService I am doing this ...

```
ExchangeService myService = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2010);
myService.Credentials = new WebCredentials("myName", "myPassword");
myService.AutodiscoverUrl("myEmailAdddress@myCompany.com");
```

... and then create an appointment using ...

```
Appointment a = new Appointment(myService);
```

etc. When I run this it works okay and sets me as the organiser of the meeting. But when I deploy the site - presumably I need to put in the user's UserName and Password so that they become the organiser of the meeting as Appointment.Organiser is read-only. But I don't know and can't access their Username and Passwords. So how, within a .net web application, can different users access the Exchange Web Services so that they appear as the organizer of a meeting?

While testing I am putting in the UserName and Password I use to log in to windows

Answer (score 0):

You must impersonate the user in order to have that user as the organizer.
1. Initialize the Exchange service with a service account which has the Impersonation rights.
2. Impersonate the users using their email address.
3. Create the appointment.

This way the service account is impersonating the user and create the appointment just like the user is creating the appointment him/herself.